# ImportError: No module named bitarray

Tags: python-2.7, fuzzy-c-means

I am trying to implement fuzzy c means algorithm in Python..I have used the builtin function to do the same in Matlab.I would like to know whether there is any such simple method in Python also.I tried

http://peach.googlecode.com/hg/doc/build/html/tutorial/fuzzy-c-means.html

I have tried this :

```
from numpy import *
import peach as p

    x = array( [
        [ 0., 0. ], [ 0., 1. ], [ 0., 2. ], [ 1., 0. ], [ 1., 1. ], [ 1., 2. ],
        [ 2., 0. ], [ 2., 1. ], [ 2., 2. ], [ 5., 5. ], [ 5., 6. ], [ 5., 7. ],
        [ 6., 5. ], [ 6., 6. ], [ 6., 7. ], [ 7., 5. ], [ 7., 6. ], [ 7., 7. ] ] )

    mu = array( [
        [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ],
        [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.7, 0.3 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ],
        [ 0.3, 0.7 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ],
        [ 0.3, 0.7 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ], [ 0.3, 0.7 ] ] )


    m = 2.0

    fcm = p.FuzzyCMeans(x, mu, m)

    print "After 20 iterations, the algorithm converged to the centers:"
    print fcm(emax=0)
    print "The membership values for the examples are given below:"
    print fcm.mu
```

but getting *** ImportError: No module named bitarray ***

Can anyone help?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Did you try installing it?

Comment: @Kishore I have edited my post.plz go thru

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes I tried installing bitarray-0.8.1 but it seems like it is not installed properly..I am using windows 8 32 bit.

Comment: spin up a python console and check if this - `from bitarray import bitarray` works. If you get an `importError`, check in the python dist-packages directory if the module exists.

Comment: @Kishore I tried and couldnt find the module in site-package directory ..So how can I proceed?I have downloaded the bitarray package zip file..but I dont know where is it to be extracted?in site-package directory?It have tried that also..but didnt work..

Comment: Have a look at this - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. Forgot the `sudo` when doing `pip install bitarray`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is just because you are in the installed folder of the package so that you could not import it. Try to go somewhere else and rerun it.